# React js ES5 module.exports issue

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-5

**File name = main.jsx**

```
var React = module.exports = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
var SchoolsList = require("./components/SchoolsList.jsx");
var schoolsStore = require("./stores/schoolsStore");
var _schools = [];
var getSchoolsCallback = function(schools){
    _schools = schools;
    render();
};
schoolsStore.onChange(getSchoolsCallback);

function render(){
    ReactDOM.render(<SchoolsList schools={_schools} />, document.getElementById("container"));    
}
```

**File name = app.jsx**

```
//var React = require("react");
var SchoolInfo = require("./SchoolInfo.jsx")
var AddSchool = require("./AddSchool.jsx");

module.exports = React.createClass({
   render:function(){
       return(
           <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <AddSchool />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    {
                        this.props.schools.map(function(s,index){
                            return(
                                <SchoolInfo info={s} key={"school"+index} />
                            )         
                        })
                    }
                </div>
           </div>
       )
   } 
});
```

I used `var React = module.exports = require("react");` in `main.jsx` file. That module used all class, so I used exports module using `module.exports`. But I can't React module use in another class. If that possible if exports module in main file and I can access that module in all class?

Comment: please explain your question clearly

Comment: In app.jsx file without require React module i want access that module, because i declare that module in main.jsx file

Comment: i dont want to use **var React = require("react");** in app.jsx file because i used **var React = module.exports = require("react");** in main.jsx file

Comment: Why would you export a library? I don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: i want export React library and want access in all competent for that library.

Comment: any particular reason why you dont want to use traditional require?  ```var React = require('react')```